# In wso2 api manager, how to add a custom mediator

Tags: wso2

I read the post at [WSO2 API Manager and XACML Entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949590/wso2-api-manager-and-xacml-entitlement) which says that a configuration file in API Manager can be modified to use an entitlement mediator in "the in sequence".

I know how to edit this configuration through the web interface. But which file contains this configuration?

This configuration doesn't have a  element or  element (except for the  elements in  elements). Exactly where should I put the  element?

If I create my own entitlement mediator, how do I plug it in or make it available to the API Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to APIM distribution,HOME\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api folder,where you will see the api configurations, which you create from publisher. Add your mediator there, by editing the configuration and restart the server.