# Configure WSO2 API Manager 1.8 AS PEP for WSO2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to use API Manager as a PEP so it can redirect my request to PDP(wso2 Identity server). I have seen some bolgs where they are using Oath Authorization server in-between, but don't want to use that par. Is it possible to configure API Manager to work as PEP which can directly talk to identity server?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949590/wso2-api-manager-and-xacml-entitlement

Comment: That article is not the exact answer of my question. Now API manager 1.8 support XACML feature also. so my question is how we can use API manager as PEP to call Wso2IS for evaluate xacml policy against API call.